# display the content of an arraylist (controller) to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

## edit

I have a method returns an ArrayList which display products. I had created a controller

```
final String inputFileName = "Onto.owl";
String categorie = "Mode";
String nom = "HasName";
String description= "HasDescription";

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
    modelAndView.addObject("pList", GetAllFonction.displayProducts(inputFileName, categorie));

    return modelAndView;
}
```

then I iterate using `c:foreach` on the the ArrayList(pList)

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${pList}">
  <tr>
  <td> <c:out value="${value}"/></td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

but the table is empty.

Comment: debug to ensure that `GetAllFonction.displayProducts(inputFileName, categorie));` actually returns some values

Comment: I am thinking that list is empty. Can you make sure.Code seems ok

Comment: Can you give an example of data inside arraylist? Also, please add the complete jstl code from your jsp.

Comment: @Lucky @soorapadman the arraylist content  `[Bagues Metalique, Montre Daniel Weilington, Boucles Geometrique]`

Comment: try to check whether your list  empty or not in jsp...                                      <c:if test="${empty pList}">the List is empty</c:if>

Answer (score 0):

please check `GetAllFonction.displayProducts(inputFileName, categorie)` method is returning any values or it is empty.

**OR**

instead of this line

```
modelAndView.addObject("pList", GetAllFonction.displayProducts(inputFileName, categorie));
```

You can add below code to cross check it

```
List<String> **list**=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("vishal");
list.add("biradar");

modelAndView.addObject("pList",**list**);
```